# Did rebase of git from remote branch, after rebase, branch info is lost

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-remote

I have a remote branch : let's say X
and i have a mirror or above : Let's say Y
With in Y, i have another branch feature.

I wanted to rebase feature with X, so tried following command :
git rebase X/master Y/feature

After this, branch info is lost, and i am not able to push any changes.

Any pointers??

Comment: You cannot rebase a remote-tracking branch...

Comment: If  torek's answer fully answered your question, please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 3):

As Jubobs noted [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28805140/did-rebase-of-git-from-remote-branch-after-rebase-branch-info-is-lost#comment45884607_28805140), you can't do that.

More specifically, as the documentation notes:

> `git rebase` ... [*`upstream`* [*`branch`*]]
>
> If *`branch`* is specified, `git rebase` will perform an automatic `git checkout branch` before doing anything else. ...

In your example you wrote:

> `git rebase X/master Y/feature`

Here, *`upstream`* is `X/master`, and *`branch`* is `Y/feature`, so the rebase process starts by doing `git checkout Y/feature`.

If you try this yourself, you will see:

> ```
> Note: checking out 'Y/feature'.
>
> You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
> changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
> state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.
> ```

So, `git rebase` will start by putting you into "detached HEAD" state.  It will then do the usual rebase operation using `X/master` as the upstream for the newly-detached HEAD.

This has a well-defined meaning, but is probably nothing like what you intended (though it's not clear to me what you did intend).